# What terminology should I reference to learn how to break down CISC instructions?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to learn the fundamentals needed in order to be able to analyze CISC architecture executable binary instructions and break down each instruction into its components including the opcode and address.

The following diagram I [found here](http://www.quadibloc.com/arch/srisc0301.htm#:%7E:text=The%20memory%2Dreference%20instructions%2C%20as,for%20the%20opcode%20is%20sufficient.&text=There%20are%20four%20possible%20opcodes.) is almost exactly what I'm looking for, but whereas I'm new to the subject, the diagram or accompanied article doesn't elaborate on certain terms, symbols, and concepts, which leaves me trying to search the subject to learn more so I can understand what's going on, but Google doesn't return useful results with the terms I'm searching.

[image]

Perhaps it's just an issue of not knowing what terms to search. What terminology should I be using to reference what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The website you found describes hypothetical architectures. You could Google for “intel instruction set manual” or “arm instruction set manual” to get descriptions of current so-called CISC and RISC architectures. (“So-called CISC” because today practically everything is RISC except sometimes the instruction decoder).

Comment: So if I analyze the binary instructions in a dll or exe or anything on a typical desktop PC, I can assume the instructions are in RISC format? Is there a way to verify which architecture I'm looking at? Also why do you think you were down-voted?

Comment: On most PCs, instructions will be CISC instructions. Typically the instruction decoder will translate them automatically into RISC instructions; but you never see those.

Comment: @J.Todd The binary instructions in a DLL or EXE on a typical desktop PC are x86 or x64 instructions because that's what type of processor is in a typical desktop PC.

Comment: @user253751 yep finally made that connection

Comment: @J.Todd Note that the ".NET Framework" is a thing and although .NET programs get stored in EXE and DLL files, they're completely different. They (might) not contain x86 or x64 instructions, they might contain instructions for the .NET Framework interpreter instead.